# Could AndroidViewClient still work well with Monkeyrunner?

Tags: androidviewclient

I'm using `AndroidClientView` to do automated test. I found when the phone came into a new page, `ViewClient` should dump the whole view. I guess if there is a way to speed up the test process, such as the page is only a transferred page, I don't need to get the specific ids of all the widgets, I just want to click a coordinate to pass through quickly. So I try to use Monkeyrunner with `AndroidViewClient`, But I tried lots of ways, there were alway errors showed up. like "syntax error" "import error" or other errors..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to identify any elements of the new screen and you know exactly the coordinates of the point you are going to tap then there's no need to invoke `dump()`.

As an example, this is a slightly modified `culebra`-generated test. It uses Calculator to enter an operation and verify the result, but as we know that the buttons are not changing we can comment out all the `dump`s and `sleep`s, and the result is the same but the test executes much faster.

```
def testSomething(self):
    if not self.preconditions():
        self.fail('Preconditions failed')

    _s = CulebraTests.sleep
    _v = CulebraTests.verbose

    self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''clear''').longTouch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(u'com.google.android.calculator:id/digit_1').touch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''plus''').touch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(u'com.google.android.calculator:id/digit_2').touch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''multiply''').touch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(u'com.google.android.calculator:id/digit_3').touch()
    #self.vc.sleep(_s)
    #self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''equals''').touch()
    self.vc.sleep(_s)
    self.vc.dump(window=-1)
    self.assertEquals(u'7', self.vc.findViewById(u'com.google.android.calculator:id/result').getText())
```